# Jquery and Ajax not working right

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Sorry if this is a question with a obvious answer but my knowledge with Jquery is very limited and I don't have any idea how to debug this.

Basicaly on my site I have a ranking script (see here working nfrases.com in the middle box) that reads if the user clicks up or down and then a jquery script picks the vote, sends it to ajax.php that do the mySQL queries and it refreshes the $rating value. I followed a tutorial so everything went pretty smooth to achieve this.

Now I'm trying to reproduce it at http://www.nfrases.com/modelo2.php?tag_nome=vida but nothing works ... already tried a million variations (not realy knowing what I was doing) and nothing worked. The jquery script is out of the scripts.js for more easily debbuging  but I'll paste here the the problematic areas so I can better help you help me!

Thanks in advance!

HTML part:

```
            <ul id="caixacontainer2">       
                <li id="m<?php echo $id_frase ?>">
                    <div class="vote2 <?php verification that returns "active" or "inactive" ?>">  
                        <span class="up"></span>
                        <span class="down"></span>
                        <span class="rating2"><?php echo $rating ?></span>                        
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

jQUERY part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ul = $('ul.caixacontainer2');

$('div.vote2 span').live('click',function(){

    var elem        = $(this),
        parent      = elem.parent(),
        li          = elem.closest('li'),
        ratingDiv   = li.find('.rating2'),
        id_frase    = li.attr('id').replace('m',''),
        v           = 1;

    if(parent.hasClass('inactive')){ return false; }
    parent.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    if(elem.hasClass('down')){ v = -1; }
    ratingDiv.text(v + +ratingDiv.text());
    var arr = $.makeArray(ul.find('li')).sort(function(l,r){ return +$('.rating2',r).text() - +$('.rating2',l).text(); });
    ul.html(arr);
    $.get('ajax.php',{action:'vote',vote:v,'id_frase':id_frase});
    });
});
```

Also ... is it possible the problem derive from already having a `$(document).ready(function(){` inside the file scripts.js ?

Thanks again, appreciate all the help you can give me debbuging this as I feel completely lost here!

Cheers

Comment: You can have as many $(document).ready() definitions as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you should do some debugging. See what gets executed and what not. It seems to me this line is erroneous and that the execution stops there:

```
ratingDiv.text(v + +ratingDiv.text());
```

One `+` is redundant.

Also: for requests to change things on the server you are supposed to use `post` (not `get`). This might not matter practically, but sometimes it does (when `get` requests are configured to be cached and therefore not sent again, while `post` requests are not).

Comment: Hey Tom. Your answer shed light on the problem, tho the + might not be so redundant cause I have the scrtipt up and runing perfect on the main page of the site. As you said the execution stops at ratingDiv.text(v + +ratingDiv.text()); and this might be caused by the script don't now what is ratingDiv specificaly. I think ratingDiv is defined ratingDiv = li.find('.rating2'), but the thing is there are 10 ratingDiv on that page... is it any way to distinguish them ? Like per example how it's done for the definition of id_frase...

Comment: It seems `ratingDiv` refers to the third `span` you have (it is found by the class `rating2`. And it is the one inside the `closest li`. It doesn't seem there is more than one. Maybe there are more in other places, but inside the `closest li` there is only one. If there are more you can give them different `id`s to distinguish between them). I looked at it again and the extra `+` is indeed not redundant. Where exactly does the execution stop? What are the values of the variables there?

Comment: I don't realy know where the execution stops Tom. I know that the ajax.php doesn't receives the request (so the problem surely has to be in the jQuery part). I also must say the HTML I posted in this question is inside a loop, if you see the source of http://www.nfrases.com/modelo2.php?tag_nome=vida you'll see the html I posted here repeats 10 times inside that page.

Comment: If you want to program, you should be willing to debug. What do you mean you don't know where the execution stops? Then find out! You can use a debugger (like FireBug), or even the good old mediaeval method of `alert()`-ing in various places and see which `alert()`s get called. (I see you added an `alert()` as a success function - that's great! Add more `alert()`s every second line all the way to that AJAX call!)

Answer (score 2):

I guess one of the first step would be use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or any similar framework, and to see in the network tab if your **get** request is sent to the server or not.

Second, I would suggest having at least a success callback as shown [in the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)  to see if the call is successful.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I now have firebug, the Network tab doesn't show anything when I click eother the up or down vote. Also put a callback function to pop an alert and nothing happnes also!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('ajax.php',{action:'vote',vote:v,'id_frase':id_frase});
```

You are making an ajax call but you never provide any success callback to do when the ajax is finished. You need to give it a function name (or anonymous function) to execute when the ajax finishes.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Did that with no result. I'm almost almost sure the problem is not from the ajax.php as I already have it working on www.nfrases.com ... The problem must surely be with the elements name in modelo.php?tag_nome=vida and the way they are picked up buy the jQuery.